# When calculating sample variance around a sample mean can I take degrees of freedom to be a fraction

Tags: variance, covariance, degrees-of-freedom, bessels-correction

Normally if you have $N$ samples of a random variable, from which you estimate both the sample mean and sample variance, you need to account for the missing degree of freedom in the sample variance:

$$Var(X) = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum^N_{i=1} (x_i - \bar{x})^2 $$

But what if the sample mean is estimated from a larger dataset that includes the $N$ samples, as well as some others (say you are interested in a timeseries of variance over some time windows, while estimating the mean over the entire time range). Say the larger dataset used for the mean has $(N + M)$ points, would it be sensible to divide by $N - \frac{N}{N + M}$?

Strictly speaking, there are (at least) $N$ degrees of freedom in the calculation for variance, but perhaps the above would be less biased.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is meant be "you are interested in a timeseries of variance over some time windows", but I don't think the answer is likely to be this simple. It sounds like the variance you are interesting in estimating has a different meaning than the usual sense of the word. In order to derive the relevant correction, you'll have to write out the estimator explicitly and take its expectation. You might find the proof (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction#Alternative_1) of the formula you state in your post a useful starting point

Comment: I guess I should properly phrase my question as: if I want an unbiased estimator of the true variance of $X$, what should P be in $\frac{1}{P}\sum_i^{M} (x_i - \frac{1}{N} \sum_i^N x_i )^2$, where $N > M$. Actually I worked it out in the meantime, I'll post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are considering the sample mean:

$$\bar{X}_{N+M} = \frac{1}{N+M} \sum_{i=1}^{N+M} X_i.$$

The sum-of-squared deviations around this value is:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \bar{X}_{N+M})^2
&= \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i^2 - 2 \bar{X}_{N+M} X_i + \bar{X}_{N+M}^2) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 - 2 \bar{X}_{N+M} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i + N \bar{X}_{N+M}^2 \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 - \frac{2}{N+M} \sum_{i=1}^{N+M} \sum_{j=1}^N X_i X_j + \frac{N}{(N+M)^2} \sum_{i=1}^{N+M} \sum_{j=1}^{N+M} X_i X_j. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Assuming your data is IID with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ you have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 \bigg) 
&= N (\sigma^2 + \mu^2), \\[6pt]
\mathbb{E} \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{N+M} \sum_{j=1}^N X_i X_j \bigg) 
&= N [\sigma^2 + (N+M) \mu^2], \\[6pt]
\mathbb{E} \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{N+M} \sum_{j=1}^{N+M} X_i X_j \bigg) 
&= (N+M) [\sigma^2 + (N+M) \mu^2]. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

We therefore have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \bar{X}_{N+M})^2 \bigg)
&= \mathbb{E} \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 - \frac{2}{N+M} \sum_{i=1}^{N+M} \sum_{j=1}^N X_i X_j \\[6pt]
&\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad + \frac{N}{(N+M)^2} \sum_{i=1}^{N+M} \sum_{j=1}^{N+M} X_i X_j \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= N (\sigma^2 + \mu^2) - \frac{2N}{N+M} [\sigma^2 + (N+M) \mu^2] \\[6pt]
&\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \ + \frac{N}{N+M} [\sigma^2 + (N+M) \mu^2] \\[6pt]
&= N (\sigma^2 + \mu^2) - \frac{N}{N+M} [\sigma^2 + (N+M) \mu^2] \\[6pt]
&= N \sigma^2 + N \mu^2 - \frac{N \sigma^2}{N+M} - N \mu^2 \\[6pt]
&= \bigg( N - \frac{N}{N+M} \bigg) \sigma^2 \\[6pt]
&= N \bigg( 1 - \frac{1}{N+M} \bigg) \sigma^2 \\[6pt]
&= \frac{N (N+M-1)}{N+M} \cdot \sigma^2. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Consequently, we obtain the following unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$:

$$S_*^2 \equiv \frac{N+M}{N (N+M-1)} \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \bar{X}_{N+M})^2.$$

In the special case where $M=0$ this reduces to the usual sample variance estimator.

Answer (score 0):

This can be worked out directly. We seek to find $P$ such that if sample variance is defined as

$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{P} \sum^M_{i=1} (x_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N}_{i=1} x_i)^2 $$

with $N \geq M$ then

$$E(\hat{\sigma}^2) = Var(X)$$

**Answer**: after some working out, what I get is that you should choose $P$ as

$$P = M \cdot \frac{N-1}{N}$$

For $M = N$, this is $N - 1$ as expected, and for $N = 100$, $M=50$, this is $49.5$ (nicely equal to the average of the cases with 0 and 1 missing degrees of freedom).

Comment: The assumption that the mean of the larger group is applicable for the smaller group needs to be thought about.

Comment: This is helpful, but a full derivation instead of *after some working out* could be even more helpful.

Comment: yeah, I'm still very curious as to why you would want to calculate the mean using a larger sample population, but be interested in deviations away from said mean, across a smaller population.

Comment: For example, if you have time series data where you believe the mean is constant over time, but the variance changes over time, you can calculate the mean from the full time series, but you may be interested in looking at variances over smaller windows in time.